# org-export-filter-final-output-function appears not to fire

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I'm trying to filter my org-export output in one file because every heading in the ascii output seems to have two line breaks after it:

```
first heading 
=============


second heading
==============
```

And I want it to be:

```
first heading 
=============

second heading
==============
```

So I added this function to my org file:

```
#+BIND: org-export-filter-final-output-functions (tmp-f-singlebreak)
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :exports results :results none
  (defun tmp-f-singlebreak (s backend info)
    (message "inside singlebreak function")
    (replace-regexp-in-string "\\n\\n" "\\n" s))
#+END_SRC
```

I added the `message` call so that I could debug whether the function was ever actually running. There is nothing in the messages buffer when I export using `org-export-dispatch` so I can only guess that the function is not being called.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you enable the `BIND` keyword by setting `org-export-allow-bind-keywords` to `t`? See the last paragraph of the `Export Settings` section of the manual (`C-h i g(org)Export settings` will get you there). Also, did you refresh the setup by pressing `C-c C-c` on the `#+BIND:` line or by killing the buffer and reopening the file?

FWIW, it fires for me - in the sense that I get the message that the function is indeed called.

But there is also a problem with the function. If you want a single empty line between the headings, you can't forget that there is also a newline at the end of each heading. So what you want to do is replace three or more newlines with exactly *two* newlines: one to end the heading line and the other to produce the empty line:

```el
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :exports results :results none
  (defun tmp-f-singlebreak (s backend info)
    (message "inside singlebreak function")
    (replace-regexp-in-string "\n\n\n+" "\n\n" s))
#+END_SRC
```

The regexp matches three or more newlines and replaces them with two newlines. Note also that `\n` matches a newline; `\\n` matches an `n`. You can experiment with `re-builder` to see what a particular regexp matches.

You also probably want to limit the function to backends that make sense (the `ascii` backend in this case):

```el
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :exports results :results none
  (defun tmp-f-singlebreak (s backend info)
    (when (eq backend 'ascii)
      (replace-regexp-in-string "\n\n\n+" "\n\n" s)))
#+END_SRC
```